# Moving to google app engine make curl return errno 3

Tags: php

For some reason when I moved my source code to google app engine,

curl start to return error number 3:

> - CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT (3) - The URL was not properly formatted.
> - important to say that the request got properly and still return error numer 3.

Any ideas?

Attach curl call:

```
<?php
function fire($url) {
    try {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        $err_code = curl_errno($ch);
        if ($err_code) {
            return $err_code;
        } else {
            return $content;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What does your URL look like?

Comment: i tried also to do curl to clean file that just echo a string, and still got the same results .. however here is the original link i used .../index.php?prdid=480&subid=131207467617145725388&geo=xx&p1=1243&p2=vdds&p3=1&p4=lp7&ip=&esi=&cid=